# Append content to element dynamic without changing the event that introduced it

Tags: jquery

We are using a JSON file as a data source for some description texts on our website. The element to which I would like to append the description gets created only when a certain event is fired (I don't know the name of the event)

This is my current code:

```
jQuery('.preview-text').append('<p style="font-size: 20px;">' + text + '</p>');
```

The elements which gets created in the future is obviously `.preview-text`. Since it's not present when the document is loaded, it doesn't append the required text to it when it gets created. How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can try `$('.preview-text').load(function(){  $(this).append('<p style="font-size: 20px;">' + text + '</p>'); });`

Comment: are you using ajax to get json data?

Comment: Before using callbacks of any kind: Does anything prevent you from appending the element A to the to-be-created element B at the time you create element B?

Comment: if u r using ajax to get element please change asynchronous to synchronous ajax ;)

`jQuery.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
});`

Comment: @V4KK4R very few element tags trigger `load` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know/can't access the event that brings `.preview-text` into the DOM, you'd have to make a periodic check for that element. You could use `setInterval` for that.

This will check the length of `$('.preview-text')` and if it is truthy, the element exists on the page, it will proceeds to append your paragraph and clear the interval.

```
var checkInterval = setInterval(function(){
    var $previewText = $('.preview-text');
    if($previewText.length){
        $previewText.append('<p style="font-size: 20px;">' + text + '</p>');
        clearInterval(checkInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/28x2fvnc/)